# Algebraic Data Types and Equality

Tags: haskell, equality, functor

Given the following data type from [TypeClassopedia](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Laws):

`data Cons a = Cons a (Cons a) | Empty deriving (Show, Eq)`

I implemented its evil Functor implementation:

```
instance Functor Cons where
    fmap _ Empty       = Empty
    fmap f (Cons x xs) = Cons (f x) (Cons (f x) (fmap f xs) )
```

Then, I attempted to write a function (quickcheck property) that takes a `Cons a` and returns a `Bool`:

```
prop_id_functor_law :: Cons a -> Bool
prop_id_functor_law x = fmap id x == id x
```

However, I get a compile-time error:

```
Prelude> :l EvilFunctor
[1 of 1] Compiling EvilFunctor      ( EvilFunctor.hs, interpreted )

EvilFunctor.hs:18:23:
    No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of `=='
    Possible fix:
      add (Eq a) to the context of
        the type signature for prop_id :: Cons a -> Bool
    In the expression: fmap id x == id x
    In an equation for `prop_id': prop_id x = fmap id x == id x
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

My rough intuition is that this compile-time error makes sense. How could two `a`'s be compared **unless** they implemented the `Eq` typeclass?

However, what did the `deriving ... Eq` even do when I defined `data Cons a`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says you need to add the constraint to `prop_id_functor_law`, so it'd be `prop_id_functor_law :: Eq a => Cons a -> Bool`.  The `deriving` part just means it derives the instance

```
instance Eq a => Eq (Cons a) where
    Empty == Empty = True
    Cons a1 x1 == Cons a2 x2 = a1 == a2 && x1 == x2
    _ == _ = False
```

You still have that the type parameter is constrained in order for the `Eq` instance to be satisfied.  If you were to check `:info Cons` in GHCi, you'd see that instance.

Answer (score 2):

> what did the `deriving ... Eq` even do when I defined data `Cons a`?

When you derive an instance, GHC always mechanically generates an instance that implements the logic required by the type class for the structure of the type. For example:

```
data Foo = Foo Int Int
  deriving Eq
```

Will give you something like:

```
instance Eq Foo
  where Foo a b == Foo a' b'
          = a == a' && b == b'
```

But if you had instead:

```
data Foo a b = Foo a b
  deriving Eq
```

Then it can tell it needs to follow the same structure (`Foo`s are equal if both contained fields are equal) but it is forced to delegate to equality for the types `a` and `b` for part of the comparison. These aren't always types that *have* equality, so the derived instance has to declare that they do as constraints:

```
instance (Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (Foo a b)
  where Foo a b == Foo a' b'
          = a == a' && b == b'
```

The same thing happens for your `Cons`. So two `Cons a` values are comparable for equality **when a values are comparable for equality**. A function like `prop_id_functor_law :: Cons a -> Bool` is declared to work for all `Cons a` values, whether or not `Eq a` holds, so the type checker will not allow you to call `==` on `Cons a` within the implementation; it might not support equality, and guaranteeing that you never call unsupported operations is the point of type checking. But if you instead had `prop_id_functor_law :: Eq a => Cons a -> Bool`, then you could use `==` (and the responsibility moves to the *callers* of `prop_id_functor_law` to ensure they call it for types that support equality).